# When you use shared pointers what is the mechanism that releases the memory from the shared pointer itself

Tags: c++

I understand that shared pointers work by counting references and releasing the object the pointer is pointing to. But the shared pointer takes space itself, is it released somehow? is there a pool of shared pointers and they are reused? is this something easy to track in the library source code?.

Comment: `shared_ptr` will be a stack object and the memory gets freed up when the function/block ends.

Comment: It use RAII, and `std::shared_ptr` release the memory when it destroyed.

Comment: Thanks, I am not a smart man

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The place where you store the shared pointer is up to you, the same way any other variable.

For instance, if you have it as a local variable in a function, then it will likely be held in the stack.

Comment: So when the context of the variable ends, the variable ends with it also?

Comment: @RaulLapeiraHerrero Yes, like with any other variable. If you have an `int`, it also takes space, and it will also be "destructed" at the end of the scope.

Comment: @RaulLapeiraHerrero Note that once you create your object and(/via) the first shared pointer pointing to it, an associated _control block_ is _likely_ to be dynamically allocated, no matter the storage duration of the shared pointer which instantiation was the reason of the instantiation of the control block. This may be particularly interesting in implementations where the control block does not hold the managed object itself (but just a pointer to the managed object).

Comment: @RaulLapeiraHerrero I think you need to click on the check mark near the voting arrows to make it green (and thanks!). See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers